# Can't install freeglut3-dev package linuxmint?

Tags: linux, opengl, freeglut, linux-mint

I tried to install freeglut package to work with #opengl 
I installed freeglut3 package
but i got this error when trying to install freeglut3-dev package

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
freeglut3-dev : Depends: libgl1-mesa-dev or
                          libgl-dev
             Depends: libglu1-mesa-dev but it is not going to be    installed or
                      libglu-dev
             Depends: libxt-dev but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: libxext-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

> The information of my system
>
> Linux version 3.14.0-031400rc4-generic (apw@gomeisa) (gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) ) #201402232235 SMP Mon Feb 24 03:36:35 UTC 2014

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I solved my problem by disabling some Personal Package Archives ('PPAs').

 It may contain some broken packages!
I disable the following PPA's:

```
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/thopiekar/pygame/ubuntu raring main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/thopiekar/pygame/ubuntu raring main
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding an answer here to document how I fixed this, since the accepted answer didn't help me.

When I tried to install freeglut3-dev, synaptic said it didn't need to upgrade or remove anything, but it wanted to uninstall a few hundred packages, including things like pulseaudio or libxml2 that couldn't possibly depend on glut3-dev. On the command line I got this:

```
> sudo apt-get install freeglut3-dev
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 freeglut3-dev : Depends: libgl1-mesa-dev or
                          libgl-dev
                 Depends: libglu1-mesa-dev but it is not going to be installed or
                          libglu-dev
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

dpkg reported no "hold" packages. I tried to install libgl1 and libglu1 manually, but those refused to install also. Finally in synaptic I checked the dependencies tab for gl1 and glu1 and found both depended on mesa-common-dev, which was already installed. On a lark I reinstalled mesa-common-dev, and that somehow magically fixed all the dependencies. I was able to install libgl1-dev, libglu1-dev, and glut3-dev without any hiccups.

Hoping this helps someone.

Answer (score -1):

Try this solution: https://askubuntu.com/questions/588695/cant-install-libglew-dev-because-libcheese-and-libclutter-dont-have-the-requir/592440#592440?newreg=ccee8cb44f5342a1aaa9a30e22128c24

It worked for me.